# Eclipse/Maven: JUnit tests not compiled when running them

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit

I am working on a project using Maven and Eclipse (m2eclipse plugin). I've got problems with the JUnit tests:

Sometimes, when running them within Eclipse, they wont be compiled, but the old class files are used instead. When I delete the class files, I get `ClassNotFoundExceptions` in Eclipse. I then have to manually recompile them by using `mvn test-compile` or other goals.

I also noticed that the class files of the tests sometimes are put into the `classes` subdirectory instead of `test-classes`.

I really can't figure out what is wrong.

The JUnit java files are within `src/main/java` and are correctly named (`*Test.java`).

Do I have to compile and run them always via Maven? Why doesn't Eclipse compile the files when I want to run them? (Interestingly, *sometimes* it does. Sometimes everything works perfectly.)

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem *after* I upgraded my Eclipse STS and AspectJ plugins to the latests.

Comment: Same problem here. Also upgraded and it was working fine before.

Comment: By convention test classes go to `/src/test/java`, not `/src/main/java` ...

Answer (score 89):

I had the same problem with STS Eclipse (Spring development variant), m2e and JUnit. The solution was to set the output folder for `src/test/java` to `target/test-classes`:

1. Right click the `src/test/java` folder in the Package Explorer
2. Select ***Build Path*** -> ***Configure Output Folder***
3. Enter `target/test-classes`, click ***OK***

Now the changes in test classes are compiled correctly and you should be able to run JUnit tests in Eclipse.

The problem is that Eclipse compiles the unit tests to the default output folder `target/classes` while JUnit plugin correctly tries to run them from `test-classes`.

There are a few duplicates to this question:

- [ClassNotFoundException when running JUnit unit tests within Eclipse (using Maven)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974432/classnotfoundexception-when-running-junit-unit-tests-within-eclipse-using-maven)
- [Eclipse doesn't see my new junit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586457/eclipse-doesnt-see-my-new-junit-test)
- [junit not using the newest file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161267/junit-not-using-the-newest-file)

Comment: To get the same result automatically, right-click on the project, and select Maven->Update Project Configuration...

Comment: @paulcm: Thanks for the tip! The "Update Project Configuration" seems to fix many problems on the Eclipse side when I've updated the pom.xml manually, imported a project or just opened one.

Comment: just as said @paulcm http://blog.xemantic.com/2008/06/maven-integration-for-eclipse-and.html

Comment: That solved my problem. It persists years after as well.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the answer below

> 1. Right click the src/test/java folder
> 2. Select Build Path -> Configure Output Folder
> 3. Enter target/test-classes, click OK

you should check to ensure that your builder is setup correctly by right clicking your project and going to **Properties -> Builder**. If you see that your builder is missing, you need to install one. In my case, the maven project had an AspectJ dependency and when I used the Maven Eclipse plugin to build my Eclipse project, it was looking for an AspectJ builder by default. I installed the AspectJ development tools and it solved the problem.

Hope this helps!

Comment: “the answer *below*” does not really work on a voting-rank-based platform, and “*the* answer” does not really work on a dynamic multi-answer platform either.

Comment: Thank you. I upgraded today to Eclipse Luna, and was having this exact problem for the same reason. I installed the dev version of AJDT for Luna (from http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/44/dev/update/) and my project now builds with Eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

The most likely explanations for the problem you are facing is that the output folder of `src/test/java` is not correctly configured.

Instead of [fixing this configuration manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8895652/1523648), you can have m2eclipse fix this for you: Just right-click on the project and choose *Maven > Update Project*.

Comment: Too late but, this option worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

And another point: JUnit test classes should be in src/test/java, not src/main/java, otherwise they aren't detected correctly by Maven as test classes and they would be included in the packaged jar and not in the test jar.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue. Tried above suggestions of configuring output folder & Maven>Update Project but neither worked. Finally changed my testOutputDirectory to "build/classes" as well and now Unit Tests are getting picked up and executed.

Finally found the reason for the issue. In my pom we had also configured maven compiler plugin as below

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <outputDirectory>build/classes</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
       </plugin>
```

outputDirectory configuration is not needed and was the cause of above issue. After removing this tag, junits are getting compiled to build>testclasses folder and are being run during maven build as well. Yippee :)

Answer (score 1):

> Please check "testSourceDirectory" path which can be configured in your
>   pom.xml. And then, Add the folder (configured in "testSourceDirectory" path) to the eclipse build path.

Please find the sample "testSourceDirectory" in pom.xml below:

```
<build>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
     <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>      
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that is there any exclamation mark on your project icon!  In my case, i ignored that there is a exclamation point like:
[exclamation point on project icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctQR9.png)

Open the "Markers" perspective, then troubleshoot the problems according to the tips.
[what the "Markers" perspective show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aptF2.jpg)

The junit test classes can be execute successfully after i called "mvn clean test" because they are not refer the unreadable jar which be warned in "Markers" perspective.Therefor, it's easily to ignore it..

Comment: I had an exclamation mark. The errors view in eclipse said that I am missing a source folder /src/test/resources and "project cannot be build until build pather errors are resolved". After I created the folder the code was compiled again.

Answer (score 1):

For someone working on java-scala mix project, this is something to note.
Even after doing the configuration in the manner shown below,

```xml
<build>
    <testOutputDirectory>${basedir}/target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <plugins>
    ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <testSourceDir>${basedir}/src/test/scala</testSourceDir>
                <testOutputDir>${basedir}/target/test-classes</testOutputDir>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and doing a *Maven > Update Project*, eclipse honours the output directory of the src/test/java folder in the project, however, not for the src/test/scala folder. (You can figure this out by right-clicking on the specific source folder and choosing *Build Path > Configure Output Folder...* which should display the location as specified in the pom for the former case, however, not for the later case.

This is already a known bug for using scala with m2e as mentioned here: http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/m2eclipse/

> Warning
>
> As of March 2013, a bug causes both src/main/scala and src/test/scala to use the default output folder (target/classes). This may be confusing >when building tests, since their class files will not end in target/test-classes, as they would when building on the command line. You can work around this by manually changing the output folder for src/test/scala.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is not expecting anything else to be mucking with the class files. It assumes that if you haven't editted the file in eclipse it hasn't changed and doesn't need compiling. I think the issue stems from eclipse and maven sharing an output directory. I've often seen this if my mvn build fails, it will have deleted the class files as part of the clean but not compiled new ones. I think the best solution would be to have seperate build dirs for mvn and eclipse, but I've never look into this.

Comment: I have seen what your talking about but this is not it. Its like Eclipse will not reload the classes for JUnit. I think its an AspectJ issue not a Maven one.

Answer (score 0):

My problem wasn't the JUnit plugin but rather the configuration in my pom.xml.

After reviewing all the answers to this question, @Gulats's answer implied to me that I should try setting a `testOutputDirectory` in my maven-compiler-plugin section, and that did the trick:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>
    <testOutputDir>${basedir}/target/test-classes</testOutputDir>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite attempting all of the solutions mentioned above, my issue remained unresolved. However, I was able to successfully resolve it by modifying the file permissions, which was the root cause of the problem.
Change the ownership of the directory and its contents recursively to your user name and the group "sudo" using the "chown" command with superuser privileges.

```
sudo chown $USER:USERGROUP -R ~/path
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two typical problems that can occur:

**The output folder is misconfigured**

Solution A

1. Right click on `Project` > `Properties`
2. Go to `Java Build Path`
3. Ensure that the output folders are set correctly (Typically `target/test-classes`)
   [image: Changing Output Folders for Test Files]

Solution B

1. Right Click on `Project` > `Maven` > `Update Project...`
   [image: Updating Project with pom.xml]

**The project nature does not have the java nature configured**

1. open the `.project` file
2. Look at the buildSpec section (example before changes)

```xml
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
```

3. Add the `org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder` build command (example after changes)

```xml
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments />
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
```