# Eclipse JUnit glitch

Tags: eclipse, junit

I wrote two unit tests in Eclipse IDE. Now I realise that my tests are possibly cached. Please take a look at my screenshot:
[image]

Eclipse says I've got TWO tests, while really I've got only one. I try to clean projects, but it has no effect.

Comment: Ok, I've found the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8895652/2713969