# Maven does not generate target test-classes file

Tags: java, maven, testng

Our company has its own maven repository and we download maven dependencies from there. When i run maven clean test on command line, it does not generate target classes and test classes from java file.

Questions:

1. **The target > test-classes
   does not have the .class file generated when running mvn clean test.**

Please help. Thanks.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Automation-Framework</groupId>
  <artifactId>Automation-Framework</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>ChromeTestManager.java</include>

                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
        </plugin>

        </plugins>


    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```

Commandline Output:

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects [INFO] Deleting target folder 
    [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6:resources (Default resources) @ Automation Framework 
    [WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent 
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile 
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources [INFO] Copying 0 resource [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1testCompile [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classess up to date 
    [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0.-M3:test (default-test) @ Automation-Framework 
    [Info] Build Success
```

Comment: have you tried `mvn clean install`

Comment: Please add the command line output of your build to the question.

Comment: @JFMeier , Simply calling Clean Test wont work, at-least he should have a install phase to get compiled files saved locally.

Comment: Added commmand line output.

Comment: @VishwaRatna nope, it will work - compile is prior test and will be done.

Comment: Maybe you dont have test classes.

Comment: I have test classess under src/test/java -> TestManager.java

Comment: It has nothing to do with your custom maven repository. Remove this `maven-surefire-plugin` plugin, keep you `pom.xml` as simple as possible. You should get test classes under `target/test-classes` folder.

Answer (score 0):

You could see in the Commandline Output you have pasted which says

`[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources [INFO] Copying 0 resource [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1testCompile [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classess up to date`

You are missing the   `maven-resources-plugin` in your build conifguration.

Add following to your `<build><plguins>  </plugins></build>`

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The resources files are copied from `src/main/resources` to `target/classes`.

EDIT: 
It doesnot help. There is 0 resources copying. The target - classess is generated but not target - test-classes.

Comment: The resources plugin is by default bound to the life cycle which means no need to add it manually...and the log shows that it is called only that no resources exist to copy...

Comment: @khmarbaise you are right. I misunderstood it. Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't help. No resource is copying after added the plugin. The target->classes is generated but not the target-test-classes.

Comment: @nicholas hope you have already checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087690/eclipse-maven-junit-tests-not-compiled-when-running-them

Answer (score 0):

Rebuilding project fixed this issue for me.