# junit not using the newest file

Tags: java, junit

I use junit automatically installed by maven. When I run the maven test my tests work fine. But when I call the Eclipse JUnit test it doesn't use the current version of the test class.

E.g. if I change a  `assertTrue()` into a `assertFalse()` I get the same result. This is driving me crazy.

Automatic build for the project is on. Why does JUnit use some old crap?

Thanks for the help. A maven clean and a eclipse clean fixed the problem. Weird...

Comment: Seems to be an issue with IDE.. Clear the output directory and rebuild the whole project.

Comment: JUnit doesn't chose the version, eclipse does.

Comment: Have you enabled 'Build automatically' in the Project menu?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse/Maven: JUnit tests not compiled when running them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087690/eclipse-maven-junit-tests-not-compiled-when-running-them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most possibly Maven compiles to ./target/classes while Eclipse usually compiles to ./bin/classes.

You should try the http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/ plugin for Eclipse that helps out easing the differences between Maven and Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

So, go to directory in which maven copied junit file from junit repository, then check the junit version.
so after thath, right click on your project under eclipse than select "Buildpath"> "add library" then select "Junit" next select "junit version" tehn continue.
after clean your project, build it, finally launch it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and managed to solve it by manually entering the proper output folder for the compiled tests in "Java build path" under the project properties.

In my case, I wanted the tests to end up in ./target/test-classes.

I think it didn't work at first because Eclipse put the compiled tests either in the wrong folder (.bin/classes) or the default output folder (./target/classes).