# Recent changes made for junit class in eclipse is not reflecting when running junit

Tags: eclipse, junit4

I tried all solutions mentioned on stackoverflow.com

[junit not using the newest file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161267/junit-not-using-the-newest-file)
[Eclipse/Maven: JUnit tests not compiled when running them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087690/eclipse-maven-junit-tests-not-compiled-when-running-them)

but junit change made in eclipse is not updating class file in target/test-classes, only running mvn install is causing .class file to be updated. In other module of maven, its working properly, but except one of this. Please help.

Comment: Click on Project - Build Automatically

Comment: Build Automatically is already checked.

Comment: Click Maven -> Update Project...

Comment: Also tried it already

Comment: Is it a multi-module project? Or are the tested functionality in another project? Are you using m2e or `mvn eclipse:eclipse`?

Comment: Its a multi module project, testing a class present in same module, and test class in src/test/java and using m2e

Comment: what is output folder in project build path? double check if it is same as maven target directory.

Comment: for src/main/java it is target/classes and for src/test/java its target/test-classes

Comment: Try `mvn clean`, followed by Project > Clean + Start a build immediately.

Comment: I tried it but sorry it didnt worked